# Is it illegal to play a cover song?

Tags: copyright

A group decides to cover a protected piece of music. In this example, lets say "[Bohemian Rhapsody by Queen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1nGx4DX83U)".

- Is the act of playing this song violate any copyright law?
- Does it make a difference if they make money off playing a cover?

Comment: This answer could be improved by specifically asking if this is a live performance and/or recorded.

Comment: You need a license to perform copyrighted music in public. See https://www.ascap.com/help/ascap-licensing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless they have permission or pay the required royalty: **yes**.

If they are playing it for personal entertainment or at a private function then they can make a fair use/dealing defence.

Comment: This answer should include a source(s) and possibly some case history.

Answer (score 3):

There are generally two copyrights for a song:

1. First, the copyright on the composition (song in the abstract).
2. Second, the copyright on the actual performance of the song.

If you're playing a cover, then the copyright on the original performance doesn't apply, but there's still the copyright on the composition. You are generally allowed to cover a song without permission of the writer, as long as you pay a rate set by statute. This is known as "compulsory license": https://www.thebalance.com/what-is-a-compulsory-license-in-music-2460357

Comment: Want to highlight that the article states the compulsory license is "A compulsory license lets a musician record (and sell) a rendition of a previously recorded song" and "a compulsory license only applies to music that is distributed to the public to be listened to by the end user."